# How to create Google Captcha with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add google Captcha with validation my all fields are working properly but when i add google captcha than it's not working i am sharing my code below.
Thanks in advance.. Also check following link Click Here [Form live link](http://skyliteweb.in/form/)

```js
$('#test').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },


    fields: {
  firstName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '<span class="error-msg">A name is required.</span>'
                    }
                }
            },
        email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: '<span class="error-msg">An email address is required.</span>'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: '<span class="error-msg">Email address is not valid.</span>'
                }
            }
        },
   phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '<span class="error-msg">A phone number is required.</span>'
                    }
                }
            },
    state: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '<span class="error-msg">A state is required.</span>'
                    }
                }
            },
   value: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '<span class="error-msg">A property value is required.</span>'
                    }
                }
            },
   loan_amount: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '<span class="error-msg">A loan amount is required.</span>'
                    }
                }
            },
   loanpurpose: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '<span class="error-msg">A loan purpose is required.</span>'
                    }
                }
            }       
    }
});


    $('#test').on('status.field.bv', function(e, data) {
        formIsValid = true;
        $('.form-group',$(this)).each( function() {
            formIsValid = formIsValid && $(this).hasClass('has-success');
        });
        
        if(formIsValid) {
            $('.submit-button', $(this)).attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('.submit-button', $(this)).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

```css
input[type="submit"]:disabled {
    background-color: red;
}
.error-msg{
color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="http://skyliteweb.in/form/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://skyliteweb.in/form/0a3b9034e109d88d72f83c9e6c9d13b7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<form id="test" action="test.php">
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
        </div>        
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" size="35" placeholder="Email*"></input>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control"  type="text"  id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number:" />
        </div>
  <div class="form-group">
            <select class="select form-control" id="state" name="state">
       <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
    <option value="California">California</option>
    <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
    <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
    <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
    <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
    <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
    <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
    <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
        </div>
   <div class="form-group">
           <input class="form-control" id="value" type="text" name="value"  placeholder="Value" />
        </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="loan_amount" type="text" name="loan_amount"  placeholder="loan Amount" />
        </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <select class="select form-control" id="loanprogram" name="loanpurpose" >   
       <option value="">Loan Purpose</option>
    <option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
    <option value="Refinance Current Loan">Refinance Current Loan</option>
    <option value="Refinance &amp; Cash-Out">Refinance &amp; Cash-Out</option>
      </select>
        </div> 
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le-AR0TAAAAAPJ_jRb62dQlMWSoLl0a1P73NxJW"></div>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success submit-button" style="width: 100%;" value="Sign Up!" type="submit" disabled></input>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see the Google captcha code anywhere?

Comment: I have not added now ..

Comment: No check i have added the Captcha code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use "getResponse()" predefined function for validation.

```
function control(){
   var msg = '';
   if($('#name').val() == '') msg += 'Invalid Name';
   if($('#email').val() == '') msg += 'Invalid Email';
   if($('#phone').val() == '') msg += 'Invalid Phone';

   if(!grecaptcha.getResponse()) msg += 'Please confirm you are not a robot';
   if(msg){
      alert(msg);
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: But i have required the same functionality of validation.. Submit not visible while user not fill all required fields...

Comment: if(!grecaptcha.getResponse()) msg += 'Please confirm you are not a robot'; this line validate Captcha in front-end side. Click here http://www.turkishfx.com/tr/basvuru/demo to see an example.